# How to change the order of model in change_list in django admin

Tags: python, django

I really stuck with a very simple task (well, at first glance it is simple). I need to re-order the change list in the admin. I have categories, some categories are nested, so they have 'parent_id' foreign key related to the same table.

So, the only thing I need is to have all the categories listed in appropriate order.

Instead of:

```
"Category1
subcategory_of_category3
Category2
subcategory_of_category_4
"
```

I need:

```
"Category1
---subcategory_of_category1
Category2
----subcategory_of_category2
"
```

And nothing else!

What I already tried:

1. provide my own QuerySet with appropriate ordering. Does not work, because it seems impossible to perform such sorting and grouping in queryset
2. I tried to override change_list.html template. But there is custom tag "list_results" and if I delete it, I'm loosing all very nice features of django admin.

I'm sure that I'm not the first person who needs the change list ordered. The solution must be very simple, I think...

Comment: You might find [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/) useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override  go through the link [Django Snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1939/)

`Django` ordering is done in the `database level.` Unless you store the result of your `uni_code` function in the DB, `django` is not going to be able to natively return results ordered in that fashion.

Storing an ordering value in the DB is probably the most expedient way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding order field in my DB, as Mushahid Khan advised. 
Since I need that actual administrator of the site will not need to specify the order of each category manually, I had to override save() method in the model.

Maybe it is very lame and ugly desicion, but it works just fine for my project. I decided that the owner of the site will want to specify order of each category, assuming that the order will be nested. That means, for example, we have 'Category-1', and 'SubCategory-1-1', 'SubCategory-1-2' and so on. If we specify order of 'SubCategory-1-1' - it will affect to the order within parent category (i.e. 'Category-1').

I decided to use alphabetical order, as it seems to me much simpler to calculate and modify. 
Here is the source of my save() method

```
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    if self.category_parent_id is not None:
        self._level = '2'
        if len(self.category_parent._order[0:-1])<2:
             self._order = '%s%s%s%s' % ('a', self.category_parent._order[0:-1], self.category_order, self._level)
        else:
            self._order = '%s%s%s' % (self.category_parent._order, self.category_order, self._level)
    else:
        self._level = '1'
        self._order = '%s%s%s%s'%('a', self.category_order, self._level, str(self.id))
        for child in self.children.all():
            child._level = '2'
            if len(self._order[0:-1])<2:
                 child._order = '%s%s%s%s'%('a', self._order[0:-1],  child.category_order, child._level)
            else:
                child._order = '%s%s%s'%(self._order,  child.category_order, child._level)
            super(Category, child).save()
    super(Category, self).save()
```

It needs to be optimized, I think, but for now it just works.